# Why does document.elementFromPoint not find the top-most element?

Tags: javascript, html

In the documentation for [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) it states:

> Returns the element from the document whose elementFromPoint method is
>   being called which is the topmost element which lies under the given
>   point.

But I do not see this behavior.  Instead, it seems to select the bottom-most element.  This is actually the behavior I want, but I am concerned as to why it doesn't match the documentation and I want to understand why in order to prevent possible future bugs.

I have created [a fiddle to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/MXFGL/1/).  If you click on the bolded but un-italicized text, it return the `B`, not the `P`.  If you click the bolded and italicized text, it returns the `I` not the `P`.  Isn't the paragraph the top-most element which contains all of these objects, or my definition of "topmost" different from the spec?

I have tried this on both Firefox and Chrome and get the same result in each.

Comment: Be very careful with this object because it is implemented differently in different browsers.  Some browsers return the x,y position based on the window and some based on the viewport.  See http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/ for a good explanation.

Comment: @Michael No, I haven't read correctly the question (or there was an edit). And now I fail to see how OP could think it should not return `I`... If I follow the apparent reasonning, it should always return the document element...

Comment: @Michael thanks, I am looking at that now.

Comment: @dystroy cognitive dissonance.  i was reading the spec one way and it was conflicting with common sense and what i was observerating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the terminology.

By "top-most" they mean the one that has the highest z-index, or is *above* other elements in view, not in terms of hierarchy.

Comment: ah okay that makes sense.  i figured it might be something like that, but z-index didn't occur to me. so it is fact always the most nested tag containing the coordinates with the highest z ordering then?

Comment: @Michael Yep. Note that it isn't only the z-index. Absolutely positioned elements which are over other elements are also considered "top-most". [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MXFGL/2/)